# AbstractMethodError on obscure method name when upgrading from Scala 2.12 to 2.13

Tags: scala, sbt, slick

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.pack.ReceiverDAO does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void com$pack$proj$dao$JSDAO$_setter_$jsDAOApi_$eq(slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile$API)' of interface com.pack.proj.dao.JSDAO.
```

when I try to promote my code to Scala 2.13 from 2.12 (the dependency that's giving me issues, `com.pack.proj`, is compiled by Scala 2.12). I thought an easy way to get rid of this error is to implement a stub for it. However, at the moment, I don't have the source code for `com.pack.proj.dao.JSDAO` (which is what I `extends` in my "receiver", `com.pack.ReceiverDAO`) so I am not sure how to `override` `com$pack$proj$dao$JSDAO$_setter_$jsDAOApi_$eq(slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile$API)` w/o compilation errors like "overrides nothing". **How can I override this inherited `abstract` method or otherwise get rid of this runtime error?**

For the sake of completeness, I'd like to add that I needed to `exclude` some of the Scala_2.12-compiled Slick libraries when I declared the troublesome library, `com.pack.proj` as a dependency:

```scala
("com.pack.proj" % "js-dao_2.12" % ProjVer)
  .exclude("com.typesafe.slick", "slick-hikaricp_2.12")
  .exclude("com.github.tminglei", "slick-pg_2.12")
  .exclude("com.typesafe.slick", "slick_2.12")
```

Answer (score 6):

You simply cannot use a library that is compiled with 2.12 in a 2.13 project. It will inevitably break.
There is no real remedy other than use a version of that library that is compiled with 2.13, or not use it at all.

Comment: I believe the problem that @juanchito is facing is caused by the issue found here: https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/issues/387

I've posted a solution to it

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're initialising your database in the same format as recommended. I.e. use a trait to define which extensions you wish to use and then extend this trait on a companion object.

```scala
import com.github.tminglei.slickpg._

trait MyPostgresProfile extends ExPostgresProfile
                          with PgArraySupport {

  override val api = MyAPI

  object MyAPI extends API with ArrayImplicits {
}

object MyPostgresProfile extends MyPostgresProfile
```

You can see a more complete example in the slick-pg [README](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/blob/master/README.md)